# Adjust panel size bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I'm using circosJS (d3.js library  for visualisation. This is my sample code. I'm not able to adjust the visualisation inside the bootstrap panel-body. I've set max-height to adjust panel size, but it's not taking effect...

[**FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/nicgirault/ora3ktym/)

```js
var layout_data = [{
  "len": 31,
  "color": "#8dd3c7",
  "label": "January",
  "id": "january"
}, {
  "len": 28,
  "color": "#ffffb3",
  "label": "February",
  "id": "february"
}, {
  "len": 31,
  "color": "#bebada",
  "label": "March",
  "id": "march"
}, {
  "len": 30,
  "color": "#fb8072",
  "label": "April",
  "id": "april"
}, {
  "len": 31,
  "color": "#80b1d3",
  "label": "May",
  "id": "may"
}, {
  "len": 30,
  "color": "#fdb462",
  "label": "June",
  "id": "june"
}, {
  "len": 31,
  "color": "#b3de69",
  "label": "July",
  "id": "july"
}, {
  "len": 31,
  "color": "#fccde5",
  "label": "August",
  "id": "august"
}, {
  "len": 30,
  "color": "#d9d9d9",
  "label": "September",
  "id": "september"
}, {
  "len": 31,
  "color": "#bc80bd",
  "label": "October",
  "id": "october"
}, {
  "len": 30,
  "color": "#ccebc5",
  "label": "November",
  "id": "november"
}, {
  "len": 31,
  "color": "#ffed6f",
  "label": "December",
  "id": "december"
}];

var heatmap = [
  ['january', 0, 1, 1368001],
  ['january', 1, 2, 1458583],
  ['january', 2, 3, 1481633],
  ['january', 3, 4, 1408424],
  ['january', 4, 5, 1400597],
  ['january', 5, 6, 1548933],
  ['january', 6, 7, 1537059],
  ['january', 7, 8, 1517383],
  ['january', 8, 9, 1544359],
  ['january', 9, 10, 1580460],
  ['january', 10, 11, 1440710],
  ['january', 11, 12, 1417824],
  ['january', 12, 13, 1597834],
  ['january', 13, 14, 1666670],
  ['january', 14, 15, 1707785],
  ['january', 15, 16, 1656905],
  ['january', 16, 17, 1620539],
  ['january', 17, 18, 1487228],
  ['january', 18, 19, 1418230],
  ['january', 19, 20, 1666497],
  ['january', 20, 21, 1739178],
  ['january', 21, 22, 1755254],
  ['january', 22, 23, 1732520],
  ['january', 23, 24, 1702975],
  ['january', 24, 25, 1546438],
  ['january', 25, 26, 1454228],
  ['january', 26, 27, 1684766],
  ['january', 27, 28, 1759669],
  ['january', 28, 29, 1764844],
  ['january', 29, 30, 1737754],
  ['january', 30, 31, 1749857],
  ['february', 0, 1, 1577419],
  ['february', 1, 2, 1509311],
  ['february', 2, 3, 1688266],
  ['february', 3, 4, 1690517],
  ['february', 4, 5, 1719390],
  ['february', 5, 6, 1693426],
  ['february', 6, 7, 1613806],
  ['february', 7, 8, 1521449],
  ['february', 8, 9, 1473617],
  ['february', 9, 10, 1632787],
  ['february', 10, 11, 1698088],
  ['february', 11, 12, 1702137],
  ['february', 12, 13, 1690878],
  ['february', 13, 14, 1661660],
  ['february', 14, 15, 1445139],
  ['february', 15, 16, 1392075],
  ['february', 16, 17, 1565855],
  ['february', 17, 18, 1622609],
  ['february', 18, 19, 1593628],
  ['february', 19, 20, 1564282],
  ['february', 20, 21, 1569010],
  ['february', 21, 22, 1458216],
  ['february', 22, 23, 1338981],
  ['february', 23, 24, 1495727],
  ['february', 24, 25, 1554400],
  ['february', 25, 26, 1574841],
  ['february', 26, 27, 1643072],
  ['february', 27, 28, 1644590],
  ['march', 0, 1, 1500834],
  ['march', 1, 2, 1424820],
  ['march', 2, 3, 1607011],
  ['march', 3, 4, 1615301],
  ['march', 4, 5, 1559021],
  ['march', 5, 6, 1547753],
  ['march', 6, 7, 1508006],
  ['march', 7, 8, 1309583],
  ['march', 8, 9, 1189917],
  ['march', 9, 10, 1365881],
  ['march', 10, 11, 1403679],
  ['march', 11, 12, 1403001],
  ['march', 12, 13, 1397280],
  ['march', 13, 14, 1367524],
  ['march', 14, 15, 1251964],
  ['march', 15, 16, 1159217],
  ['march', 16, 17, 1334292],
  ['march', 17, 18, 1391104],
  ['march', 18, 19, 1366559],
  ['march', 19, 20, 1342872],
  ['march', 20, 21, 1327773],
  ['march', 21, 22, 1268340],
  ['march', 22, 23, 1276517],
  ['march', 23, 24, 1467731],
  ['march', 24, 25, 1503009],
  ['march', 25, 26, 1496469],
  ['march', 26, 27, 1500094],
  ['march', 27, 28, 1450254],
  ['march', 28, 29, 1240603],
  ['march', 29, 30, 1086657],
  ['march', 30, 31, 1282324],
  ['april', 0, 1, 1283014],
  ['april', 1, 2, 1270569],
  ['april', 2, 3, 1293570],
  ['april', 3, 4, 1293439],
  ['april', 4, 5, 1150461],
  ['april', 5, 6, 1050257],
  ['april', 6, 7, 1209470],
  ['april', 7, 8, 1260725],
  ['april', 8, 9, 1285887],
  ['april', 9, 10, 1266011],
  ['april', 10, 11, 1234722],
  ['april', 11, 12, 1100005],
  ['april', 12, 13, 1034963],
  ['april', 13, 14, 1221402],
  ['april', 14, 15, 1265036],
  ['april', 15, 16, 1279159],
  ['april', 16, 17, 1266882],
  ['april', 17, 18, 1241239],
  ['april', 18, 19, 1153081],
  ['april', 19, 20, 1082812],
  ['april', 20, 21, 1084284],
  ['april', 21, 22, 1245400],
  ['april', 22, 23, 1248887],
  ['april', 23, 24, 1235617],
  ['april', 24, 25, 1229560],
  ['april', 25, 26, 1117336],
  ['april', 26, 27, 1074233],
  ['april', 27, 28, 1249024],
  ['april', 28, 29, 1273337],
  ['april', 29, 30, 1246730],
  ['may', 0, 1, 1036144],
  ['may', 1, 2, 1156135],
  ['may', 2, 3, 1106555],
  ['may', 3, 4, 1041413],
  ['may', 4, 5, 1182786],
  ['may', 5, 6, 1192434],
  ['may', 6, 7, 1193624],
  ['may', 7, 8, 1047831],
  ['may', 8, 9, 1106669],
  ['may', 9, 10, 1043170],
  ['may', 10, 11, 1000001],
  ['may', 11, 12, 1205405],
  ['may', 12, 13, 1247394],
  ['may', 13, 14, 1238560],
  ['may', 14, 15, 1223267],
  ['may', 15, 16, 1199465],
  ['may', 16, 17, 1040418],
  ['may', 17, 18, 952650],
  ['may', 18, 19, 1126219],
  ['may', 19, 20, 1155800],
  ['may', 20, 21, 1173902],
  ['may', 21, 22, 1167218],
  ['may', 22, 23, 1160702],
  ['may', 23, 24, 1034886],
  ['may', 24, 25, 966509],
  ['may', 25, 26, 1156691],
  ['may', 26, 27, 1194054],
  ['may', 27, 28, 1190877],
  ['may', 28, 29, 1016149],
  ['may', 29, 30, 1068529],
  ['may', 30, 31, 993302],
  ['june', 0, 1, 935590],
  ['june', 1, 2, 1119046],
  ['june', 2, 3, 1150676],
  ['june', 3, 4, 1169570],
  ['june', 4, 5, 1162795],
  ['june', 5, 6, 1147372],
  ['june', 6, 7, 1004244],
  ['june', 7, 8, 921713],
  ['june', 8, 9, 968196],
  ['june', 9, 10, 1140341],
  ['june', 10, 11, 1152976],
  ['june', 11, 12, 1165844],
  ['june', 12, 13, 1154469],
  ['june', 13, 14, 999352],
  ['june', 14, 15, 917310],
  ['june', 15, 16, 1106649],
  ['june', 16, 17, 1141077],
  ['june', 17, 18, 1143086],
  ['june', 18, 19, 1149995],
  ['june', 19, 20, 1141059],
  ['june', 20, 21, 1008542],
  ['june', 21, 22, 939065],
  ['june', 22, 23, 1129289],
  ['june', 23, 24, 1161838],
  ['june', 24, 25, 1158130],
  ['june', 25, 26, 1159204],
  ['june', 26, 27, 1146093],
  ['june', 27, 28, 1009897],
  ['june', 28, 29, 928706],
  ['june', 29, 30, 1103970],
  ['july', 0, 1, 1143862],
  ['july', 1, 2, 1150514],
  ['july', 2, 3, 1167512],
  ['july', 3, 4, 1150024],
  ['july', 4, 5, 1008307],
  ['july', 5, 6, 934687],
  ['july', 6, 7, 1106666],
  ['july', 7, 8, 1143473],
  ['july', 8, 9, 1154196],
  ['july', 9, 10, 1167145],
  ['july', 10, 11, 1151100],
  ['july', 11, 12, 1006581],
  ['july', 12, 13, 930137],
  ['july', 13, 14, 941594],
  ['july', 14, 15, 1126558],
  ['july', 15, 16, 1166553],
  ['july', 16, 17, 1187503],
  ['july', 17, 18, 1182767],
  ['july', 18, 19, 1030447],
  ['july', 19, 20, 934780],
  ['july', 20, 21, 1107315],
  ['july', 21, 22, 1147785],
  ['july', 22, 23, 1161849],
  ['july', 23, 24, 1169049],
  ['july', 24, 25, 1131515],
  ['july', 25, 26, 993075],
  ['july', 26, 27, 925852],
  ['july', 27, 28, 1077760],
  ['july', 28, 29, 1095700],
  ['july', 29, 30, 1098378],
  ['july', 30, 31, 1096670],
  ['august', 0, 1, 1071402],
  ['august', 1, 2, 951503],
  ['august', 2, 3, 878472],
  ['august', 3, 4, 996356],
  ['august', 4, 5, 1016188],
  ['august', 5, 6, 1022237],
  ['august', 6, 7, 1027197],
  ['august', 7, 8, 1024299],
  ['august', 8, 9, 922671],
  ['august', 9, 10, 872742],
  ['august', 10, 11, 974684],
  ['august', 11, 12, 988100],
  ['august', 12, 13, 988993],
  ['august', 13, 14, 981883],
  ['august', 14, 15, 893681],
  ['august', 15, 16, 894506],
  ['august', 16, 17, 858478],
  ['august', 17, 18, 991784],
  ['august', 18, 19, 1022889],
  ['august', 19, 20, 1031167],
  ['august', 20, 21, 1038878],
  ['august', 21, 22, 1042880],
  ['august', 22, 23, 951127],
  ['august', 23, 24, 896613],
  ['august', 24, 25, 1078972],
  ['august', 25, 26, 1123401],
  ['august', 26, 27, 1122117],
  ['august', 27, 28, 1129891],
  ['august', 28, 29, 1114953],
  ['august', 29, 30, 986620],
  ['august', 30, 31, 921040],
  ['september', 0, 1, 1103673],
  ['september', 1, 2, 1143909],
  ['september', 2, 3, 1149438],
  ['september', 3, 4, 1157452],
  ['september', 4, 5, 1149054],
  ['september', 5, 6, 1010272],
  ['september', 6, 7, 942892],
  ['september', 7, 8, 1135215],
  ['september', 8, 9, 1163859],
  ['september', 9, 10, 1165798],
  ['september', 10, 11, 1163321],
  ['september', 11, 12, 1142868],
  ['september', 12, 13, 1007248],
  ['september', 13, 14, 938456],
  ['september', 14, 15, 1129580],
  ['september', 15, 16, 1160361],
  ['september', 16, 17, 1166669],
  ['september', 17, 18, 1166135],
  ['september', 18, 19, 1155657],
  ['september', 19, 20, 1013339],
  ['september', 20, 21, 939303],
  ['september', 21, 22, 1115789],
  ['september', 22, 23, 1155790],
  ['september', 23, 24, 1175290],
  ['september', 24, 25, 1171100],
  ['september', 25, 26, 1156096],
  ['september', 26, 27, 1016313],
  ['september', 27, 28, 946015],
  ['september', 28, 29, 1140783],
  ['september', 29, 30, 1171328],
  ['october', 0, 1, 1169047],
  ['october', 1, 2, 1166792],
  ['october', 2, 3, 1151218],
  ['october', 3, 4, 1013653],
  ['october', 4, 5, 961694],
  ['october', 5, 6, 1173529],
  ['october', 6, 7, 1208669],
  ['october', 7, 8, 1218388],
  ['october', 8, 9, 1203597],
  ['october', 9, 10, 1185802],
  ['october', 10, 11, 1047404],
  ['october', 11, 12, 1002951],
  ['october', 12, 13, 1176808],
  ['october', 13, 14, 1209924],
  ['october', 14, 15, 1220987],
  ['october', 15, 16, 1220765],
  ['october', 16, 17, 1193122],
  ['october', 17, 18, 1042063],
  ['october', 18, 19, 960302],
  ['october', 19, 20, 1151448],
  ['october', 20, 21, 1213130],
  ['october', 21, 22, 1255712],
  ['october', 22, 23, 1282461],
  ['october', 23, 24, 1267047],
  ['october', 24, 25, 1115921],
  ['october', 25, 26, 1086010],
  ['october', 26, 27, 1232889],
  ['october', 27, 28, 1282237],
  ['october', 28, 29, 1278848],
  ['october', 29, 30, 1258570],
  ['october', 30, 31, 1225435],
  ['november', 0, 1, 1072746],
  ['november', 1, 2, 1049955],
  ['november', 2, 3, 1272203],
  ['november', 3, 4, 1340860],
  ['november', 4, 5, 1408998],
  ['november', 5, 6, 1451479],
  ['november', 6, 7, 1437583],
  ['november', 7, 8, 1274988],
  ['november', 8, 9, 1210274],
  ['november', 9, 10, 1327675],
  ['november', 10, 11, 1246598],
  ['november', 11, 12, 1396790],
  ['november', 12, 13, 1432484],
  ['november', 13, 14, 1422153],
  ['november', 14, 15, 1275193],
  ['november', 15, 16, 1234596],
  ['november', 16, 17, 1453194],
  ['november', 17, 18, 1484727],
  ['november', 18, 19, 1514655],
  ['november', 19, 20, 1511929],
  ['november', 20, 21, 1462551],
  ['november', 21, 22, 1294247],
  ['november', 22, 23, 1202440],
  ['november', 23, 24, 1404219],
  ['november', 24, 25, 1459282],
  ['november', 25, 26, 1453893],
  ['november', 26, 27, 1454444],
  ['november', 27, 28, 1426951],
  ['november', 28, 29, 1294661],
  ['november', 29, 30, 1287777],
  ['december', 0, 1, 1549272],
  ['december', 1, 2, 1633784],
  ['december', 2, 3, 1684781],
  ['december', 3, 4, 1689624],
  ['december', 4, 5, 1666695],
  ['december', 5, 6, 1545527],
  ['december', 6, 7, 1523315],
  ['december', 7, 8, 1683824],
  ['december', 8, 9, 1754569],
  ['december', 9, 10, 1734975],
  ['december', 10, 11, 1669997],
  ['december', 11, 12, 1641086],
  ['december', 12, 13, 1489854],
  ['december', 13, 14, 1474692],
  ['december', 14, 15, 1633309],
  ['december', 15, 16, 1607862],
  ['december', 16, 17, 1632516],
  ['december', 17, 18, 1536016],
  ['december', 18, 19, 1490975],
  ['december', 19, 20, 1394406],
  ['december', 20, 21, 1387549],
  ['december', 21, 22, 1538557],
  ['december', 22, 23, 1550730],
  ['december', 23, 24, 1469007],
  ['december', 24, 25, 1314160],
  ['december', 25, 26, 1499708],
  ['december', 26, 27, 1508048],
  ['december', 27, 28, 1570757],
  ['december', 28, 29, 1792749],
  ['december', 29, 30, 1770200],
  ['december', 30, 31, 1721354]
]

days_off = [
  ['january', 0, 1, 2],
  ['january', 1, 2, 0],
  ['january', 2, 3, 0],
  ['january', 3, 4, 1],
  ['january', 4, 5, 1],
  ['january', 5, 6, 0],
  ['january', 6, 7, 0],
  ['january', 7, 8, 0],
  ['january', 8, 9, 0],
  ['january', 9, 10, 0],
  ['january', 10, 11, 1],
  ['january', 11, 12, 1],
  ['january', 12, 13, 0],
  ['january', 13, 14, 0],
  ['january', 14, 15, 0],
  ['january', 15, 16, 0],
  ['january', 16, 17, 0],
  ['january', 17, 18, 1],
  ['january', 18, 19, 1],
  ['january', 19, 20, 0],
  ['january', 20, 21, 0],
  ['january', 21, 22, 0],
  ['january', 22, 23, 0],
  ['january', 23, 24, 0],
  ['january', 24, 25, 1],
  ['january', 25, 26, 1],
  ['january', 26, 27, 0],
  ['january', 27, 28, 0],
  ['january', 28, 29, 0],
  ['january', 29, 30, 0],
  ['january', 30, 31, 0],
  ['february', 0, 1, 1],
  ['february', 1, 2, 1],
  ['february', 2, 3, 0],
  ['february', 3, 4, 0],
  ['february', 4, 5, 0],
  ['february', 5, 6, 0],
  ['february', 6, 7, 0],
  ['february', 7, 8, 1],
  ['february', 8, 9, 1],
  ['february', 9, 10, 0],
  ['february', 10, 11, 0],
  ['february', 11, 12, 0],
  ['february', 12, 13, 0],
  ['february', 13, 14, 0],
  ['february', 14, 15, 1],
  ['february', 15, 16, 1],
  ['february', 16, 17, 0],
  ['february', 17, 18, 0],
  ['february', 18, 19, 0],
  ['february', 19, 20, 0],
  ['february', 20, 21, 0],
  ['february', 21, 22, 1],
  ['february', 22, 23, 1],
  ['february', 23, 24, 0],
  ['february', 24, 25, 0],
  ['february', 25, 26, 0],
  ['february', 26, 27, 0],
  ['february', 27, 28, 0],
  ['march', 0, 1, 1],
  ['march', 1, 2, 1],
  ['march', 2, 3, 0],
  ['march', 3, 4, 0],
  ['march', 4, 5, 0],
  ['march', 5, 6, 0],
  ['march', 6, 7, 0],
  ['march', 7, 8, 1],
  ['march', 8, 9, 1],
  ['march', 9, 10, 0],
  ['march', 10, 11, 0],
  ['march', 11, 12, 0],
  ['march', 12, 13, 0],
  ['march', 13, 14, 0],
  ['march', 14, 15, 1],
  ['march', 15, 16, 1],
  ['march', 16, 17, 0],
  ['march', 17, 18, 0],
  ['march', 18, 19, 0],
  ['march', 19, 20, 0],
  ['march', 20, 21, 0],
  ['march', 21, 22, 1],
  ['march', 22, 23, 1],
  ['march', 23, 24, 0],
  ['march', 24, 25, 0],
  ['march', 25, 26, 0],
  ['march', 26, 27, 0],
  ['march', 27, 28, 0],
  ['march', 28, 29, 1],
  ['march', 29, 30, 1],
  ['march', 30, 31, 0],
  ['april', 0, 1, 0],
  ['april', 1, 2, 0],
  ['april', 2, 3, 0],
  ['april', 3, 4, 0],
  ['april', 4, 5, 1],
  ['april', 5, 6, 1],
  ['april', 6, 7, 0],
  ['april', 7, 8, 0],
  ['april', 8, 9, 0],
  ['april', 9, 10, 0],
  ['april', 10, 11, 0],
  ['april', 11, 12, 1],
  ['april', 12, 13, 1],
  ['april', 13, 14, 0],
  ['april', 14, 15, 0],
  ['april', 15, 16, 0],
  ['april', 16, 17, 0],
  ['april', 17, 18, 0],
  ['april', 18, 19, 1],
  ['april', 19, 20, 1],
  ['april', 20, 21, 2],
  ['april', 21, 22, 0],
  ['april', 22, 23, 0],
  ['april', 23, 24, 0],
  ['april', 24, 25, 0],
  ['april', 25, 26, 1],
  ['april', 26, 27, 1],
  ['april', 27, 28, 0],
  ['april', 28, 29, 0],
  ['april', 29, 30, 0],
  ['may', 0, 1, 2],
  ['may', 1, 2, 0],
  ['may', 2, 3, 1],
  ['may', 3, 4, 1],
  ['may', 4, 5, 0],
  ['may', 5, 6, 0],
  ['may', 6, 7, 0],
  ['may', 7, 8, 2],
  ['may', 8, 9, 0],
  ['may', 9, 10, 1],
  ['may', 10, 11, 1],
  ['may', 11, 12, 0],
  ['may', 12, 13, 0],
  ['may', 13, 14, 0],
  ['may', 14, 15, 0],
  ['may', 15, 16, 0],
  ['may', 16, 17, 1],
  ['may', 17, 18, 1],
  ['may', 18, 19, 0],
  ['may', 19, 20, 0],
  ['may', 20, 21, 0],
  ['may', 21, 22, 0],
  ['may', 22, 23, 0],
  ['may', 23, 24, 1],
  ['may', 24, 25, 1],
  ['may', 25, 26, 0],
  ['may', 26, 27, 0],
  ['may', 27, 28, 0],
  ['may', 28, 29, 2],
  ['may', 29, 30, 0],
  ['may', 30, 31, 1],
  ['june', 0, 1, 1],
  ['june', 1, 2, 0],
  ['june', 2, 3, 0],
  ['june', 3, 4, 0],
  ['june', 4, 5, 0],
  ['june', 5, 6, 0],
  ['june', 6, 7, 1],
  ['june', 7, 8, 1],
  ['june', 8, 9, 2],
  ['june', 9, 10, 0],
  ['june', 10, 11, 0],
  ['june', 11, 12, 0],
  ['june', 12, 13, 0],
  ['june', 13, 14, 1],
  ['june', 14, 15, 1],
  ['june', 15, 16, 0],
  ['june', 16, 17, 0],
  ['june', 17, 18, 0],
  ['june', 18, 19, 0],
  ['june', 19, 20, 0],
  ['june', 20, 21, 1],
  ['june', 21, 22, 1],
  ['june', 22, 23, 0],
  ['june', 23, 24, 0],
  ['june', 24, 25, 0],
  ['june', 25, 26, 0],
  ['june', 26, 27, 0],
  ['june', 27, 28, 1],
  ['june', 28, 29, 1],
  ['june', 29, 30, 0],
  ['july', 0, 1, 0],
  ['july', 1, 2, 0],
  ['july', 2, 3, 0],
  ['july', 3, 4, 0],
  ['july', 4, 5, 1],
  ['july', 5, 6, 1],
  ['july', 6, 7, 0],
  ['july', 7, 8, 0],
  ['july', 8, 9, 0],
  ['july', 9, 10, 0],
  ['july', 10, 11, 0],
  ['july', 11, 12, 1],
  ['july', 12, 13, 1],
  ['july', 13, 14, 2],
  ['july', 14, 15, 0],
  ['july', 15, 16, 0],
  ['july', 16, 17, 0],
  ['july', 17, 18, 0],
  ['july', 18, 19, 1],
  ['july', 19, 20, 1],
  ['july', 20, 21, 0],
  ['july', 21, 22, 0],
  ['july', 22, 23, 0],
  ['july', 23, 24, 0],
  ['july', 24, 25, 0],
  ['july', 25, 26, 1],
  ['july', 26, 27, 1],
  ['july', 27, 28, 0],
  ['july', 28, 29, 0],
  ['july', 29, 30, 0],
  ['july', 30, 31, 0],
  ['august', 0, 1, 0],
  ['august', 1, 2, 1],
  ['august', 2, 3, 1],
  ['august', 3, 4, 0],
  ['august', 4, 5, 0],
  ['august', 5, 6, 0],
  ['august', 6, 7, 0],
  ['august', 7, 8, 0],
  ['august', 8, 9, 1],
  ['august', 9, 10, 1],
  ['august', 10, 11, 0],
  ['august', 11, 12, 0],
  ['august', 12, 13, 0],
  ['august', 13, 14, 0],
  ['august', 14, 15, 2],
  ['august', 15, 16, 1],
  ['august', 16, 17, 1],
  ['august', 17, 18, 0],
  ['august', 18, 19, 0],
  ['august', 19, 20, 0],
  ['august', 20, 21, 0],
  ['august', 21, 22, 0],
  ['august', 22, 23, 1],
  ['august', 23, 24, 1],
  ['august', 24, 25, 0],
  ['august', 25, 26, 0],
  ['august', 26, 27, 0],
  ['august', 27, 28, 0],
  ['august', 28, 29, 0],
  ['august', 29, 30, 1],
  ['august', 30, 31, 1],
  ['september', 0, 1, 0],
  ['september', 1, 2, 0],
  ['september', 2, 3, 0],
  ['september', 3, 4, 0],
  ['september', 4, 5, 0],
  ['september', 5, 6, 1],
  ['september', 6, 7, 1],
  ['september', 7, 8, 0],
  ['september', 8, 9, 0],
  ['september', 9, 10, 0],
  ['september', 10, 11, 0],
  ['september', 11, 12, 0],
  ['september', 12, 13, 1],
  ['september', 13, 14, 1],
  ['september', 14, 15, 0],
  ['september', 15, 16, 0],
  ['september', 16, 17, 0],
  ['september', 17, 18, 0],
  ['september', 18, 19, 0],
  ['september', 19, 20, 1],
  ['september', 20, 21, 1],
  ['september', 21, 22, 0],
  ['september', 22, 23, 0],
  ['september', 23, 24, 0],
  ['september', 24, 25, 0],
  ['september', 25, 26, 0],
  ['september', 26, 27, 1],
  ['september', 27, 28, 1],
  ['september', 28, 29, 0],
  ['september', 29, 30, 0],
  ['october', 0, 1, 0],
  ['october', 1, 2, 0],
  ['october', 2, 3, 0],
  ['october', 3, 4, 1],
  ['october', 4, 5, 1],
  ['october', 5, 6, 0],
  ['october', 6, 7, 0],
  ['october', 7, 8, 0],
  ['october', 8, 9, 0],
  ['october', 9, 10, 0],
  ['october', 10, 11, 1],
  ['october', 11, 12, 1],
  ['october', 12, 13, 0],
  ['october', 13, 14, 0],
  ['october', 14, 15, 0],
  ['october', 15, 16, 0],
  ['october', 16, 17, 0],
  ['october', 17, 18, 1],
  ['october', 18, 19, 1],
  ['october', 19, 20, 0],
  ['october', 20, 21, 0],
  ['october', 21, 22, 0],
  ['october', 22, 23, 0],
  ['october', 23, 24, 0],
  ['october', 24, 25, 1],
  ['october', 25, 26, 1],
  ['october', 26, 27, 0],
  ['october', 27, 28, 0],
  ['october', 28, 29, 0],
  ['october', 29, 30, 0],
  ['october', 30, 31, 0],
  ['november', 0, 1, 1],
  ['november', 1, 2, 1],
  ['november', 2, 3, 0],
  ['november', 3, 4, 0],
  ['november', 4, 5, 0],
  ['november', 5, 6, 0],
  ['november', 6, 7, 0],
  ['november', 7, 8, 1],
  ['november', 8, 9, 1],
  ['november', 9, 10, 0],
  ['november', 10, 11, 2],
  ['november', 11, 12, 0],
  ['november', 12, 13, 0],
  ['november', 13, 14, 0],
  ['november', 14, 15, 1],
  ['november', 15, 16, 1],
  ['november', 16, 17, 0],
  ['november', 17, 18, 0],
  ['november', 18, 19, 0],
  ['november', 19, 20, 0],
  ['november', 20, 21, 0],
  ['november', 21, 22, 1],
  ['november', 22, 23, 1],
  ['november', 23, 24, 0],
  ['november', 24, 25, 0],
  ['november', 25, 26, 0],
  ['november', 26, 27, 0],
  ['november', 27, 28, 0],
  ['november', 28, 29, 1],
  ['november', 29, 30, 1],
  ['december', 0, 1, 0],
  ['december', 1, 2, 0],
  ['december', 2, 3, 0],
  ['december', 3, 4, 0],
  ['december', 4, 5, 0],
  ['december', 5, 6, 1],
  ['december', 6, 7, 1],
  ['december', 7, 8, 0],
  ['december', 8, 9, 0],
  ['december', 9, 10, 0],
  ['december', 10, 11, 0],
  ['december', 11, 12, 0],
  ['december', 12, 13, 1],
  ['december', 13, 14, 1],
  ['december', 14, 15, 0],
  ['december', 15, 16, 0],
  ['december', 16, 17, 0],
  ['december', 17, 18, 0],
  ['december', 18, 19, 0],
  ['december', 19, 20, 1],
  ['december', 20, 21, 1],
  ['december', 21, 22, 0],
  ['december', 22, 23, 0],
  ['december', 23, 24, 0],
  ['december', 24, 25, 2],
  ['december', 25, 26, 0],
  ['december', 26, 27, 1],
  ['december', 27, 28, 1],
  ['december', 28, 29, 0],
  ['december', 29, 30, 0],
  ['december', 30, 31, 0]
]

var circos = new circosJS({
  container: '#chart'
});

circos
  .layout({
      ticks: {
        display: false
      },
    },
    layout_data
  )
  .heatmap('h1', {
    innerRadius: 180,
    outerRadius: 240,
    logScale: false,
    colorPalette: 'YlOrRd'
  }, heatmap)
  .heatmap('h2', {
    innerRadius: 170,
    outerRadius: 179,
    logScale: false,
    colorPalette: 'Blues'
  }, days_off)
  .render();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nicgirault/circosJS/master/dist/circosJS.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nicgirault/circosJS/master/dist/colorBrewer.css">
<svg id='chart'></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the chart inside the panel body with center aligned. Please check the the codepen link the chart is coming inside the panel body without overflowing panel body.

[**CODEPEN LINK**](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/BzvpGX?editors=1010)

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-fw"></i> Host</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body centered">
      <svg id='chart' style="display:block; margin:auto;"></svg>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```